# Where was the TARDIS made?

Tags: doctor-who

In the Angels Takes Manhattan before the Doctor meets up with River he looks into something that looks like a mirror to fix his hair and then it comes into focus:

[image: huh?]

Does that mean the TARDIS was made by Rolls-Royce or was it just showing that the TARDIS has some Rolls-Royce pieces in it?

Comment: I had to replay that segment several times before I caught what was on the plate.  Made me wonder too...

Comment: @BBlake hehe I took that screenshot while watching it on the train ride in to work :-)

Comment: Just a minor note: TARDISs are grown, not built.

Comment: @Jeff I am asking about it being "made". Not whether it was grown or built.

Comment: Typically, things that are grown don't have builders plates.

Answer (score 16):

That's not where the TARDIS herself was made; it appears to be where one of the many random pieces of "junk" that happen to be in the TARDIS was made.

It's a [12-cylinder boat engine manufactured by Rolls Royce under license from Foden](http://www.dft.gov.uk/mca/mcga07-home/mcga-dops_fishing_engine-details?model_id=121&make=FODEN).

Might it have some deeper meaning? This *is* Doctor Who, so there is likely some interesting backstory. I don't believe that it's been told yet, though.

Comment: Specifically, that's the tally plate an engine from the RR-manufactured Griffon engine of an RAF Supermarine Spitfire.

Answer (score 5):

The TARDIS was originally formed on Gallifrey, BUT the doctor has remodeled it many times with whatever he could find. In the episode the *Doctors Wife* the TARDIS says that she has been completely remade by the doctor before. (from scratch)
So any parts could essentially be used.

Answer (score 0):

The TARDIS comes from the Blackhole shipyard on Gallifrey, but the engines are Rolls-Royce (obviously), built in England.
[image: Manufacturer's Plaque]

[image: Engine Maker's Plate]

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Do you have any evidence you can [edit] into your answer? Here we are of a Q/A site where answers are encouraged to be rooted in evidence unlike a discussion forum.

Comment: The bottom image is the one from the question so I'm not sure how that proves your point about the engines. As for the first image do you have a source for that? Is it from canon or fan made? etc.

Comment: The bottom one is from a Doctor Who still. 
In the Angels Takes Manhattan before the Doctor meets up with River he looks into something that looks like a mirror to fix his hair and then it comes into focus

Comment: I know and thanks for copying a quote from the question too. I still don't see how it helps your case though. You need to add an explanation. No where in the image does it state what that Rolls Royce image is for. So, using it and stating without a doubt it's about the engines is a bit odd.

Comment: The first image is from the Doctor Who Site and is a purchasable item. You can buy on at Forbidden Planet, I'm told.

Answer (score 0):

In the new series, the control room of the TARDIS took on a slap-dash design, to give the impression that The Doctor had patched it together with any bits of technology he could lay his hands on at the time.

That look faded away a bit with later redesigns of the set. The console still seems to have what look like earth technology mixed in - keypads with English lettering, etc. but it looks much more like a single design, and not a patchwork.

There's an idea initially introduced in (and later cut from) *The Doctor's Wife* that explains the "junk" aspect of the design.  An important scene in the episode features The Doctor and Idris building a TARDIS from what looks like complete junk from literally anything they could find laying about. (This was done to work in the winner of a "Design a TARDIS" contest from British children's show Blue Peter) A scene that got cut explains that what they see is not junk and rubbish, but parts of destroyed TARDISae, still under the effect of their chameleon circuits.

So it's *possible* that the "junk" look of those earlier control rooms (and certainly the one banged together in that episode) was simply that - a look. The chameleon circuit was disguising the various jury-rigs The Doctor made over the years, randomly disguising a disused Bambleweeny 57 sub-meson drive as two clothespins and a bit of string. POssibly because that's what she considered them no different from, or no better than.